# Changing Gridview number of columns based on position

Tags: java, android, gridview, listadapter

Im currently building an application that implements a GridView. However, i need to split the GridView up. For example, at position zeta the number of columns is 3 then at position 2 3 4 the number of columns change to 1.

I have had a look around but it doesn't look like its possible. Coming from an iOS Background ive done it before in some previous iOS projects so i thought i may be able to replicate it in android.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just a idea not sure if it would work. Making the gridView an auto_fit column,
then based on position make the item cell view width properly so the gridView could either put in multiple cells or just one cell in the row.